# $f'(0)$ in linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

T is the linear operator on $P_2(R)$ defined by

$$ T(f(x))=f(1)+f'(0)x+(f'(0)+f''(0))x^2 $$

What does $f'(0)$ and $f''(0)$ mean here?

I would have guessed both should equal zero, but that seems not to be the case, since when I try to write the operator as a matrix, I get the wrong result.

I have two introductory linear algebra books, but both just assume that this should be obvious to the reader.

Comment: If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ then $f'(x)=2ax+b$ and $f''(x)=2a,$ hence $f'(0)=b$ and $f''(0)=2a.$

Comment: @AnneBauval But what is 'b' and 'a' in this case? I don't even have a function to derive.. Thanks.

Comment: You said $T$ was defined on $P_2(R).$ Didn't you mean on $\Bbb R_2[x]$? (the space of polynomials $f(x)$ of degree $\le2$, i.e. of the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c,$ where $a,b,c$ are arbitrary constants).

Comment: Coin dropped I think. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, it is my turn not to understand: does "coin dropped" mean that you got it, or that you give up?

Comment: @AnneBauval I think it's a variation on the British idiom ["the penny dropped"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20penny%20drops), meaning they did understand what you were saying.

Comment: @Theo thanks fot this relief